# Making objects chase another (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flashdevelop

So i have an object that i want to chase another object. Everything is working fine, however i tried to implement an    easeTo    function to make it so that the object doesn't take the most direct route to the x,y locations of the object it is chasing. This also works but the thing that is really pissing that i can't fix is the fact that the objects speed changes depending how far away from the object it is chasing is. For example, if the object being chased is on the far right of the stage and the chaser spawns on the far left, it will go really fast towards the object on the right and slow down as it gets closer. I would love for it to go at a consistent speed. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Here is my code

```
        private function easeTo(cur:Point, target:Point, ease:Number):Point{

        var dx:Number = target.x - cur.x; 
        var dy:Number = target.y - cur.y;


        var finalResult:Point = new Point(); //create a var to hold the result

        finalResult.x = cur.x + (dx * ease);
        finalResult.y = cur.y + (dy * ease);

        return finalResult;


    }



    public function chase(xValue:Number, yValue:Number):void{

            //store current x and y in a point var
            var curPos:Point = new Point (x,y);

            //store the mouse x and y in a var
            var targetPos:Point = new Point(xValue, yValue);


            var nextPos:Point = easeTo(curPos, targetPos, 0.001);

            this.x = nextPos.x;
            this.y = nextPos.y;

    }
```

So the    (xValue:Number, yValue:Number)    is the x and y values of the object it is chasing being passed into the    chase    function.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Math.min (when dx or dy is negative) and Math.max (when dx or dy is positive) with a value you define to be your max speed

ie:

```
var maxSpeed:Number = 20;
if (dx >= 0){
   dx = Math.max(dx,maxSpeed)
}else{
   dx = Math.min(dx,maxSpeed)
}
```

repeat for dy